# Model wrapper for sklearn cross_val_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, wrapper, xgboost, cross-validation

This is an minimal example using `XGBClassifier`, but am interested how this would work in general. I am trying to wrap the model class in order to use it in cross validation. In this case I am only weighing the imbalanced classes, but my ultimate goal is a bit broader change in the pipeline.

My first try was to simply override the fit function:

```py
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_sample_weight
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedStratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin

class WeightedXGBClassifier(XGBClassifier, BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_weights(y):
        sample_weights = compute_sample_weight(class_weight='balanced', y=y)
        return sample_weights
    
    def fit(self, X, y, **kwargs):
        weights = self.get_weights(y)
        super(XGBClassifier, self).fit(X, y, sample_weight=weights, **kwargs)
```

which works fine, when I'm trying to fit the model, use predictions etc.. But using this in sklearn `cross_val_score`

```py
xgb_model_cv = WeightedXGBClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=4, alpha=100, use_label_encoder=False)

cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
auc_scorer = metrics.make_scorer(metrics.roc_auc_score, needs_proba=True)
scores = cross_val_score(xgb_model_cv, X, y, scoring=auc_scorer, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
```

throws an error

```
File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pyTF/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 767, in _score
    scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pyTF/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 106, in __call__
    score = scorer._score(cached_call, estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pyTF/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 306, in _score
    y_pred = self._select_proba_binary(y_pred, clf.classes_)
AttributeError: 'WeightedXGBClassifier' object has no attribute 'classes_'
```

Now, it is my understanding the `classes_` attribute is created, when the model is fitted, but I am not sure how to then properly wrap the model to capture this. Note that running

```py
model = XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder=False, scale_pos_weight=(~y).sum()/y.sum())
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='roc_auc', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
```

works fine. My second try was:

```py
class XGBClassifierWrapper(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
#         super(BaseEstimator).__init__()
#         super(ClassifierMixin).__init__()
        self.xgb_classifier_obj = XGBClassifier(**kwargs)
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_weights(y):
        sample_weights = compute_sample_weight(class_weight='balanced', y=y)
        return sample_weights
    
    def fit(self, X, y, **kwargs):
        weights = self.get_weights(y)
        self.xgb_classifier_obj.fit(X, y, sample_weight=weights, **kwargs)
        return self
    
    def predict(self, X, **kwargs):
        return self.xgb_classifier_obj.predict(X, **kwargs)
    
    def predict_proba(self, X, **kwargs):
        return self.xgb_classifier_obj.predict_proba(X, **kwargs)
```

which again resulted in the same error as in the case above, i.e., missing `classes_` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I don't actually get an error when I run any of your code; however, I do get a `scores` consisting only of `nan`, and adding `error_score='raise'` I get your error message.)

In the first approach, I believe the only real problem is in your initialization. `super(XGBClassifier, self)`: that's looking for a parent class *of* `XGBClassifier`, and not `XGBClassifier` itself, as I assume you want.  Replacing with just the vanilla `super()` and everything works.

You should also add `return self` to the end of `fit` in your first attempt, but it's not important here.  You can probably safely drop `BaseEstimator` and `ClassifierMixin` from the inheritance, since `XGBClassifier` already inherits from them.

Your second, wrapper, approach just fails because the wrapped `xgb_classifier_obj` has all the fitted attributes, including `classes_`, but your wrapper doesn't expose that directly.  You can just set `self.classes_ = self.xgb_classifier_obj.classes_` in `fit`, or perhaps define a `@property` delegation.

You should also consider that your `__init__` this time doesn't meet the sklearn API, so cloning won't work correctly.  I'd advise using the first approach for this reason (fixing it requires rather more tedious work, in my opinion).

Comment: Thanks! A clear and thorough answer. One question though, `XGBClassifier` does not seem to have the `classes_` attribute, so the second approach does not seem to work even with `@property` properly defined. I was then wondering, why does simply overriding the fit function work with out an AttributeError?

Comment: @xan `XGBClassifier` does have a `classes_` attribute, after it is fit. I didn't actually try the property approach, just the direct setting of the attribute; what goes wrong?  In which way of overriding fit do you expect the error? (Fitting worked in both of your approaches, it errored at scoring.)

Comment: That's right, fitting works fine in both cases. Defining a property `classes_` in the second case, and running the `cross_val_score` throws `AttributeError: 'XGBClassifier' object has no attribute 'classes_'`

Comment: @xan Adding the property works fine for me, `@property` newline `def classes_(self): return self.xgb_classifier_obj.classes_`?

Comment: Got it. I was adding the property to the constructor and naturally before running fit, there is no `classes_`, that's why the error was thrown. Thank you for taking the time, much appreciated!!